# Eclipse unable to resolve akka reference in maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, akka

I am trying the akka tutrials that remotely deploys the pi calculation. I am using the mvn project with eclipse juno. I have been able to install the maven pluggin for eclipse and successfully run the first pi claculation. Now  I am trying the second pi tutorials which involves remote deployment of actors. But when I open the tutorials package in the eclipse IDE  looks like some of the akka files are not been resolved by the system. I have defined the dependencies in the POM but still eclipse and maven complain. When I run the maven compile goal in the eclipse, the project gets compiled but when i try to run it it gives me error.  Below are the sample code snippets.

```
import akka.actor.UntypedActor; 
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.routing.CyclicIterator;
import akka.routing.InfiniteIterator;
import akka.routing.UntypedLoadBalancer;
eclipse complains that it cannot resolve the above importation
```

this is the POM.XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <name>Akka.Remote.Cluster</name>
  <groupId>Akka-Remote_Cluster</groupId>
  <artifactId>Akka.Remote.Cluster</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <url>http://akka.io</url>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency> 
   <dependency>
  <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
  <artifactId>akka-remote</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>          
</dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>typesafe</id>
            <name>Typesafe Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

this is the error from eclipse

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at Akka_Remote_Cluster.Akka.Remote.Cluster.Pi.main(Pi.java:16)
```

Any suggestion on what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed a similar problem with deleting and redownloading the required Maven artifacts. The first download was somehow broken.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to manually import `config-0.3.1.jar` from the akka distribution (inside libs)